# Calculating $P(X < \frac{1}{2} \mid Y = \frac{1}{2})$

Tags: probability

**Problem:** Let

$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
c(x + y^2) & 0 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } 0 \le y \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find $P(X < \frac{1}{2} \mid Y = \frac{1}{2})$.

**Attempted Solution:**

First note that:

\begin{split}
P\left(Y = \frac{1}{2}\right) &= \int_0^1 c\left(x + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \right)dx \\
                   &= c \int_0^1 x + \frac{1}{4} dx \\
                   &= c \frac{1}{2} + c \frac{1}{4} \\
                   &= \frac{3}{4} c
\end{split}

The next calculation is the same as the one above except instead of instegrating from $0$ to $1$ we integrate from $0$ to $1/2$:

\begin{split}
P\left(X < \frac{1}{2}, Y = \frac{1}{2}\right) &= \int_0^{1/2} c \left( x + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \right)  dx \\
                  &= c \int_0^{1/2} x + \frac{1}{4} dx \\
                                    &= c \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 + c \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
                                    &= \frac{1}{4} c
\end{split}

Thus

$$
P\left(X < \frac{1}{2} \mid Y = \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{P(X < \frac{1}{2}, Y = \frac{1}{2})}{P(Y = \frac{1}{2})} = \frac{(1c)/4}{(3c)/4} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

**Question:** Is my reasoning/calculation correct?

Comment: The fundamental concept is correct; HOWEVER, density functions are NOT probabilities.

Comment: Actually, $P(Y=\frac12)=P(X<\frac12,Y=\frac12)=0$, so no, this is not correct at all.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Please moderate your enthousiasm -- or whatever it is that makes you mislead the OP.

Comment: @Did Ok but is my solution wrong?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki You mean, your answer? No, it is not wrong, it leaves many things not really explained, but it is not wrong.

Comment: I see your mean. but i just was curious.

Comment: @Did However thank  u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(x+y^2)dxdy=1\implies\,c=\frac{6}{5}$$
$$f_{Y}(y)=\frac{6}{5}\int_{0}^{1}(x+y^2)dx=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{6}{5}y^2\,\,\,,\,\,\,y\in[0,1]$$
$$f_{X|Y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}=\frac{x+y^2}{\frac{1}{2}+y^2}$$
$$P\left(X<\frac{1}{2}|Y=\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)dx=\frac{1}{3}$$